# Able to print to console but cannot set label text

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I am trying to print the `JSON` response in a label (or `textField`, doesn't really matter) in the app itself. I can print to the console no problem but I cant set the `JSON` response as my label text.  Here is my code.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
       // print("Data, response, error", data, response, error)
        if let data = data {
            let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: String] ?? [:]
            print("json", json)
            let token = json?["token"] as? String ?? ""
            UserDefaults.standard.set(token, forKey: "token")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "signedIn")
        }
        //print("Data, response, error", data, response, error)
    }.resume()
```

If I try to do `label.text = ("json", json)` I get the error saying

> cannot set type [String: String]? as String

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Read the error message.. It's fairly obvious. You should be doing `label.text = token`.. `label.text = ("json", json)` obviously won't work. You cannot assign a tuple to a string variable.

Answer (score 1):

As error indicating `cannot set type [String: String]? as String` means you can not set `[String: String]?` to a `UILabel` because `label.text` only accept `String` values.

To resolve this issue you need get `String` value from your `json` dictionary. Something like:

```
let yourString = json["keyYouWantToAccess"]
```

and then assign it to your `label` text like:

```
label.text = yourSting
```

And don't forget to update your `UI` in main thread when you are working with API calls like shown below:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {

    //Update your UI here
    self.label.text = yourSting
}
```

Comment: And don't forget that the label needs to be updated on the main queue.

Comment: It was in my mind but forgot to add that into answer. :D Updating my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

`label.text` has the type `String`, while `("json", json)` has the type `(String, [String:String]?)`. You need to assign as such:

```swift
if let json = json {
  let string = "json \(json)"
  label.text = string
}
```

And follow the thread instructions as per Dharmesh Kheni's response.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that you simply want to show the whole dictionary as a string in the label.